# "Mathematical Physics"'s equivalent for Computer Science

Tags: mathematical-foundations

Mathematical Physics is a **well defined** scientific fields that deals with the application of mathematics , mathematical tools , and mathematical methods in the theories and the problems of physics.

Is there a **well defined** scientific field that deals with the application of mathematics , mathematical tools , and mathematical methods in the theories and the problems of computer science ?

Comment: Theoretical computer science?

Comment: Computer science?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use mathematics or mathematical models to understand physical nature around us and its dynamics, the mathematics in its association with physical laws become Physics. Similarly, when you leverage mathematics or its models like trees, graph, first-order logic etc to understand computational problems it becomes computer science.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical computer science?
Computational theory?

Comment: I'm not sure "computational theory" has any commonly agreed meaning. Without context, I'd probably imagine it was a mis-spoken version of "computation theory", i.e., computability, but that's much more limited than the intended scope.